# How can I make a Heaviside function?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am handling the Stanford heart transplant data in R.

```
library(survival) 
head(jasa)
```

I want to analyse survival between transplant vs non-transplant patient. But I want to use a Heaviside function.

```
> transplant(t) : 0 if did not receive transplant by time, t i.e, if t<wait-time
  1 if received transplant prior to time, i.e,
  if t> wait-time
> 
> msscore(t)  0 if t< wait-time
            mscore if t>wait-time

> age(t)      0 if t< wait-time
            AGE if t>wait time
```

I want to evaluate survival process using these Heaviside functions. Although I've searched many documents, there's no function that can make a Heaviside function in R as far as I know.

Comment: Look at `ifelse()`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what a "heaviside" function is suppose to do and what the result should look like?

Comment: `http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/fBasics/html/utils-Heaviside.html`

Comment: The exposure variable of interest in this extended
Cox model is heart transplant status at time t, denoted
by HT(t). This variable is defined to take
on the value 0 at time t if the patient has not
received a transplant at this time, that is, if t is
less than the wait-time for receiving a transplant.
The value of this variable is 1 at time t if the
patient has received a transplant prior to or at
time t, that is, if t is equal to or greater than the
wait-time.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `ifelse(t>wait-time,1,0)` and the Heaviside function in `fBasics` (probably found via `library(sos); findFn("Heaviside")`, there's a cleverer/more efficient solution via

```
H <- function(x) as.numeric(x>0)
mscore*H(t-(wait-time))
```